# Saving agents in Domino Designer 14 adds ghost libraries

Tags: java, lotus-notes, agent, domino-designer-eclipse

I recently installed Notes 14 on my computer at location c:\notes14.
As I previous had an installation of Notes on my computer at c:\notes everything in this folder was moved into the Notes14 folder by the installer, which is fine.

I now have problems saving java agents.

I have created a new database locally and added a java agent.
When I save the agent I get errors about missing references to a local path on my disk so it does not compile.

I also see libraries that have been added automatically to the agent. if I remove them they come back when I save.

the path it is refering to was indeed a folder on my disk previously but after upgrade to Notes 14 it was moved into the c:\notes14 directory.

I have tried to re-created the workspace folder but that didn't help,
I also cannot save any existing agents as the compiler adds these libraries everytimes.

the path in the error "c:\notes\data\swpdfc" is a swing software folder on my disk containg jar files, not sure why I have this on my disk, probably because I installed Swing software in an application at some point a long time ago.

Image below show the build path of the agent, you see libraries added (missing)
[image]

Image below show the error I get, If i remove the inivariable java library it is added again when I save the agent.
[image]

as the path c:\notes\data\swpdfc is not on my disk there must be some kind of setting stored somewhere that is adding these libraries

any ideas what is causing these libraries to be added everytime I save an agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have anything in your notes.ini such as JavaUserClasses that reference these jar files.

Comment: thanks, had these lines in notes.ini, problem solved by removing them 
$SwPDFJavaDir=c:\Notes\Data\SwPDFC\java\ver6.54.000\
$SwPDFJarVer=6.54.000
SWJ0=c:\Notes\Data\SwPDFC\java\ver6.54.000\swpdfc-2.0.0.jar
SWJ1=c:\Notes\Data\SwPDFC\java\ver6.54.000\iText-2.1.7-sw.jar

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually to remove those libraries from the agent?

I don't have any possibility of checking what you have done as I have not yet been able to install and run version 14 on Windows ARM...

/John

Answer (score 0):

Was that Designer client used with Swing software PDF export?